# POO en Python. Pasar información que retorna un método estático a otro método normal

Tags: python, poo, lista, objeto

Tengo esta clase hecha en Python con los siguientes métodos: load_songs, change_speed y save_songs.

```
import csv

class Song:
    def __init__(self, track, artist, genre, bpm, energy, danceability, length):
        self.track = track
        self.artist = artist
        self.genre = genre
        self. bpm = bpm
        self.energy = energy
        self.danceability = danceability
        self.length = length

    def change_speed(self, relative_bpm):         
        # ¿Cómo le pasó aquí lo que devuelve "load_songs"?
    
    # Funciona.
    @staticmethod
    def load_songs(path):
        songs = []
        
        with open(path) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            
            for row in reader:
                song = Song(*row)
                songs.append(song)
                
        return songs
    
    # Funciona.
    @staticmethod
    def save_songs(path, songs):
        with open(path, 'w') as f:
            for section in songs:
                f.write(f'{section} \n')
```

Los métodos de "load_songs" y "save_songs" funcionan. "load_song" lee un archivo CSV con el que crea un objeto con los elementos indicados en el constructor para posteriormente en "change_speed" (el método que me falta por implementar), cambiar los valores de las tres últimas columnas de la lista que devuelve "load_songs", pero la funcionalidad en sí misma de "change_speed" no es el problema.

Ahora mismo "save_songs" crea un nuevo archivo (con la misma información del archivo original) sin problemas con la información que le viene de "load_songs", pero primero debe pasar por "change_speed" para luego crear el archivo con las respectivas modificaciones. Mi duda es, **¿Cómo le paso al método de "change_speed" lo que devuelve "load_songs" para trabajar con ello?** Porque claro, no puedo iterar directamente sobre "songs" que es lo que retorna "load_songs" en "change_speed".

Por otro lado, a no ser que ser que sea un método estático, no se puede hacer una llamada al método si no has creado un objeto, pero yo no necesito crear un objeto "a mano" porque ya me lo crea "load_songs". Las llamadas a los métodos las tengo así ahora mismo:

```
import sys

from spotify import Song

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_file = 'top50.csv'
    output_file = 'top50_mod.csv'
    relative_bpm = int(sys.argv[1]) # Read keyboard input
 
    # Load songs (from input_file).
    songs = Song.load_songs(input_file)
    
    # Change speed of all songs.
    # Song.change_speed(songs, relative_bpm)
    
    # Save songs (to output_file).
    Song.save_songs(output_file, songs)
```

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: la pregunta sería, si no necesitas el objeto, qué es lo que te impide crear una clase estática  en ese método? o por qué no lo haces en una función?

Comment: @Sr1871 Quizás no me he explicado bien, pero el objeto se crea a partir de la función load_songs, es decir, aun que devuelve una lista cuando termina el bucle ya ha creado el objeto. Y según el ejercicio, con ese código base tendríamos que bastarnos para desarrollarlo.

Comment: podrías probar con  def load_songs(path): self.songs=[], por supuesto que deberás agregar el self en cada llamada y retorno de la variable y despues en:  def change_speed(self, relative_bpm): agregas por ejemplo: lista=self.songs

Answer (score -1):

Dividir para reinar:

1. Tienes una clase `Song` que implementa una canción.
2. Tienes una clase `Wurlitzer` que implementa una colección de canciones.

**Clase Song**

Contiene los detalles de una canción

```
class Song:
    def __init__(self, track, artist, genre, bpm, energy, danceability, length):
        self.track = track
        self.artist = artist
        self.genre = genre
        self.bpm = bpm
        self.energy = energy
        self.danceability = danceability
        self.length = length
```

**Clase Wurlitzer**

Maneja una colección de canciones:

```
class Wurlitzer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.songs = []
        self.relative_bpm = 0

    def load_songs(self, path):

        with open(path) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)

            for row in reader:
                song = Song(*row)
                self.songs.append(song)

    def save_songs(self, path):
        with open(path, 'w') as f:
            for section in self.songs:
                f.write(f'{section} \n')


    def change_speed(self, relative_bpm):
        for song in self.songs:
            song.bpm += relative_bpm
```

Defini `change_speed` de manera que **modifique** cada canción. No se si es lo adecuado, pero funciona si tu único interés es modificar permanentemente la canción.

En una aplicación completa, `Wurlitzer` tendría un método `play(track)` que aplica la corrección al `bpm` al momento de tocarla, sin modificar la canción misma.

Finalmente, el programa principal queda así:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_file = 'top50.csv'
    output_file = 'top50_mod.csv'
    relative_bpm = int(sys.argv[1])  # Read keyboard input

    # Load songs (from input_file).
    wurlitzer = Wurlitzer()
    wurlitzer.load_songs(input_file)

    # Change speed of all songs.
    wurlitzer.change_speed(relative_bpm)

    # Save songs (to output_file).
    wurlitzer.save_songs(output_file)
```

Comment: Gracias pero no es exactamente lo que buscaba, se supone que con ese código base que he pasado tenemos que solucionar el problema, no se necesita crear otra clase en principio.